# My node server working on desktop view of website but not mobile. Node AWS EC2 Express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

posting the code below. But a little background. My node server is hosted on an EC2 Server via AWS. My website is done with Angular Framework.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

let http = require('http');
let server = http.Server(app);
let usercount = 0;
let socketIO = require('socket.io');
let io = socketIO(server);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  usercount++;
  console.log(usercount.toString());

  socket.on('join-main-chat', (message) => {
    socket.join('main room');
    io.to('main room').emit('new-message', usercount.toString());
  });

  socket.on('change-room', (message) => {
    newRoom = message.substring(message.indexOf('-') + 1, message.length);
    let user = message.substring(0, message.indexOf('-') - 1);
    socket.leaveAll();
    socket.join(newRoom);
    console.log(user + " joined the " + message + " room");
    io.to(newRoom).emit('new-message', user + " joined the " + newRoom);
  });

  socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
    let newMessage = message.substring((message.indexOf(":") + 2), message.length);
    let currentRoom = message.substring(0, message.indexOf(":"));
    io.to(currentRoom).emit('new-message', newMessage);
    io.emit('get-count', usercount.toString());
  });

  socket.on('left-message', (message) => {
    usercount--;
    console.log(usercount.toString());
    io.emit('new-message', message);
    io.emit('new-message', usercount.toString());
    io.emit('get-count', usercount.toString());
  });
});


server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

This is working without any problems when going on my website from my desktop or laptop. This also works from many other computers. But when I try accessing it from my phone, it seems like the my phone never connects to the node server.

I'm not really sure why this happening at all?

Comment: Are the sockets required for your webview to be displayed? What mobile browser are you using to access?

Comment: chrome browser. I'm not sure about your first question. How do I  determine this?

Comment: So this looks like a chat-room app. When you open your app from your phone, you can see the app but it doesn't connect to your back-end correct? Your front end loads - but you can't get the sockets to work?

Comment: Can you go to: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-version-of-chrome-do-i-have and let us know what's the version of the chrome that you have?

Comment: you can check the connection and the events data with GUI client https://firecamp.app

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you're using Google Chrome mobile browser. [Chrome WebSocket support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) is fairly recent and the adoption rates are looking slim - you are probably on an older version. You need to update your mobile browser to get that feature.

Comment: oddly enough, it randomly started working out of nowhere